# Get User API key with PHP Pushover push notifications to iOS & Android

Tags: php, android

I want to use PHP Pushhover to push notification to specific devices / Android

```
<?php include('Pushover.php');   
$push = new Pushover(); 
$push->setToken('app token goes here'); 
$push->setUser('user token goes here');   
$push->setTitle('Hey Chris'); 
$push->setMessage('Hello world! ' .time());
$push->setUrl('http://chris.schalenborgh.be/blog/'); 
$push->setUrlTitle('cool php blog');   
$push->setDevice('iPhone'); 
$push->setPriority(0); 
$push->setTimestamp(time()); 
$push->setDebug(false);  
$go = $push->send(); ?>
```

`setToken(Your app API key)` is a server API gets from Google Project Credentials, it's fine, but where can I get the user API key for `setUser(The user's API key)`?

Note: I want to push notification to specific devices that the query choose them, and I'am using Cordova 3.4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every Pushover user has their own API key. This key is used by Pushover to send their messages to the correct users.

You can find that key at your profile page on http://pushover.net. Just login and grab your key there.

Comment: this module help me to push notification to some devices? not broadcast

Comment: Yes that is right, but pushover needs to know which devices you are targeting. That's what the user key is for.

Comment: how can I register all users and get the keys??

Comment: as you know any user install this apps! what's the way to choose specific user to push notification?

Comment: The users need to have the Pushover app installed on their phones. And they need to have an account with Pushover. Pushover is just a library to send push notifications with. It's a library that lets you send notifications trough the service of Pushover.

Comment: The best way to target specific users is to save their key into your database.

Comment: ahh ok Pataar! but I can't install pushover to all users use my apps! So please can you help me what's the best way to push notification to android using cordova? php server or what?

Comment: That is a way to do it. But it is pretty hard. Push notifications are not easy to implement. You could use a service like http://Parse.com or http://www.Notifica.re.